# How do I Set Environment variable for a multithread program?

Tags: java, multithreading, environment-variables

I would like to run a parallel Java threaded program and take advantage of multiprocessor execution. 
However I need to set the environment variable, to enable a multi-threaded environment. I understand that you can set the environment by issuing setenv PARALLEL 4 OR setenv OMP_NUM_THREADS 4 (for an OpenMP program).

This should enable 4 processors to run concurrently if you have 4 processor.

My Question is:

> 1. where do you issue the above command (SETENV) and how do you do it?

In java you can call `System.getenv("NUM_THREADS")` to get the `NUM_THREADS`. However there is no clear way of setting the environment. I am running AMD-x64 machine: OS: Windows 8, Processor: AMD E-300 APU Dual-Core processor, Ram: 4.00GB, System Type: 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the link which explains on how to set environment variable in a Windows machine **manually**:

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html

A piece taken from above link (must read the link completely, its very rich in knowledge):

---

> **Display Variables and their Values**

To list all the variables and their values, start a CMD shell (Click "Start" button ⇒ Run ⇒ Enter "cmd") and issue the command "set". To display a particular variable, use command "set varname". For examples,

```
// Display all the variables (in NAME=VALUE pairs)
prompt> set
COMPUTERNAME=xxxxxxx
OS=xxxxxxx
PATH=xxxxxxx
.......

// Display a particular variable
prompt> set COMPUTERNAME
COMPUTERNAME=xxxxxx
// OR use echo command with variable enclosed within a pair of '%'s
prompt> echo %COMPUTERNAME%
COMPUTERNAME=xxxxxx
```

Try issuing a set command on your system, and study the environment variables listed. Pay particular attention to the variable called PATH.

> **Set/Change/Unset a Variable**

To set (or change) a variable, use command "set varname=value". There shall be no spaces before and after the '=' sign. To unset an environment variable, use "set varname=", i.e., set it to an empty string.

```
prompt> set varname
prompt> set varname=value
prompt> set varname=
prompt> set
```

> **Display the value of the variable**

Set or change the value of the variable (Note: no space before and after '=')
Delete the variable by setting to empty string (Note: nothing after '=')
Display ALL the environment variables. For examples,

```
// Set an environment variable
prompt> set MY_VAR=hello

// Display
prompt> set MY_VAR
MY_VAR=hello

// Unset an environment variable
prompt> set MY_VAR=

// Display
prompt> set MY_VAR
Environment variable MY_VAR not defined
```

A variable set via the "set" command under CMD is a local variable, available to the current CMD session only.

---

If you want to set the same using Java code, below is one example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", "SET");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("MYVAR", "myValue");
Process p = pb.start();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
char[] buf = new char[1024];
while (!isr.ready()) {
    ;
}
while (isr.read(buf) != -1) {
    System.out.println(buf);
 }
}
```

If you want to pass some value to your program, you could also do that in command line:

```
java -DMyVar=varValue <main program>
```

This value could be read as:

```
String myVar= System.getProperty("MyVar");
```

Comment: If I decide to set the environment variable on the command prompt such that I have a variable named NUM_THREADS=2 and on my .java or .cpp file I have another variable named NUM_THREADS. Or assume I would like to call this variable that I initialized in the command prompt on my .java or .cpp file, how do they get to know each other? How can the .cpp file call this variable that was created in the prompt.

Comment: Do you mean that you are defining two variable in java and CPP and want each other to know about that? If so, the environment variable value is a system property, not any language specific. Once you have set it manually, it is available everywhere. But if you set it as command parameter or JVM parameter, it would be only available to that program only. If you want it to be present for all program, set it into system environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, I was having problem trying to call the variable inside a Java class. I needed to make a reference to it in a class. But I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe setenv is a command for linux/unix.

In windows 7, you can use the setx command in command prompt to set a User Environment Variable. e.g:

```
setx myvariablename myvariablevalue
```

Or you can do it through the GUI:

Right click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables